# Model not saving in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have made a drop down ajax for updating a model attribute in yii but it seems that model is not saving on the database and there is no validation error while Im checking the model

the view

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('roomType', $bed->room_type, SiteBed::roomTypes(), array('class' => 'room-types',
                'ajax' => array(
                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("admission/admit/bedUpdate", 'ajax' => TRUE)),
                    'data' => array('Bed[room_type]' => 'js:this.value', 'bed_id' => $bed->bed_id),
                    'update' => '#Bed_room_type'
                )
            )); ?>
```

the controller

```
public function actionBedUpdate()
{
    if(!isset($_POST['bed_id']))
        throw new CHttpException(400, 'Bad Request');

    if(!isset($_POST['Bed']))
        throw new CHttpException(400, 'Bad Request');

    $model = Bed::model()->findByPk($_POST['bed_id']);

    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');

    $model->attributes = $_POST['Bed'];

    $model->save();

    //    throw new CHttpException(422, 'Saving Error');
}
```

model rules

```
/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('name, status, price, room_type, house_id', 'required'),
        array('status, room_type, house_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('name', 'length', 'max'=>150),
        array('description', 'length', 'max'=>500),
        array('price', 'length', 'max'=>10),
        array('date_created, date_modified', 'length', 'max'=>14),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('bed_id, name, description, status, price, room_type, house_id, date_created, date_modified', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Comment: Show us your model rules and also do like `if(!$model->save()){  print_r($model->getErrors()); }` and see what are the errors.

Comment: hello I already did $model->getErrors() and I didn't found any errors. If I save it without ajax it working fine but if I do it with ajax it's not

Comment: try skip validation, using $model->save(false);

Comment: Yeah you can skip the validation as @Abudayah mentioned but check the rules in your model.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forget add csrf token for your post request

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('roomType', $bed->room_type, SiteBed::roomTypes(), array('class' => 'room-types',
                'ajax' => array(
                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("admission/admit/bedUpdate", 'ajax' => TRUE)),
                    'data' => array(
                      'Bed[room_type]' => 'js:this.value', 
                      'bed_id' => $bed->bed_id, 
                      'YII_CSRF_TOKEN' => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken    
                    ),
                    'update' => '#Bed_room_type'
                )
            )); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the generated jQuery code of yii is the problem, I forgot to mentioned here that I created multiple CHtml::dropDownList('roomType') because I used GridView here, the problem is that if dropDownList was generated multiple times, yii will used the id of dropdown elements which in this case is roomtype. I thought yii would use element class(room-types) instead. Thanks for the replies